# numeration of appendices

Tags: numbering, appendices

In my thesis, I have a document style `book` where I'm adding appendices as follows

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A}
\section{General concepts}
```

which for the first page looks like:

[image]

but equations there are not numerated as (A.12), instead only as (12), and Theorems numerated as Theorem .1 rather than Theorem A.1. Given that I also have appendices B and C, I would like to get enumeration (A.12) and Theorem A.1. How can I do that?

In all normal sections the enumeration is good, i.e. equation (2.15) and Theorem 2.7.

Comment: If you use `book` I assume all your normal highest-level sections are `\chapter`s. Would it be possible to use `\chapter`s in the appendix as well? Otherwise and additonal `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A}` might work as a dirty work-around (I didn't test it).

Comment: Great, it worked. Please, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `book`, your highest-level sectioning command is `\chapter`. So it would make sense to also use `\chapter` for your appendix.

```
\documentclass[british]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum
\begin{equation}x^2+y^2=z^2\end{equation}

\appendix
\chapter{General concepts}
Dolor sit amet
\begin{equation}x^2+y^2=z^2\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer to use `\section` for your appendix you need to put in a little more work.

```
\documentclass[british]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\apptocmd\appendix{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}%
  \counterwithin{equation}{section}%
  \counterwithin{figure}{section}%
  \counterwithin{table}{section}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum
\begin{equation}x^2+y^2=z^2\end{equation}
sit amet
\begin{equation}x^2+y^2=z^2\end{equation}

\appendix
\section{General concepts}
Dolor sit amet
\begin{equation}x^2+y^2=z^2\end{equation}
\end{document}
```